# Apache Ant Java API not executing all targets with dependencies

Tags: java, ant

I've created a small script to test out some of the functionality of the Ant Java api. Unfortunately, documentation at this level seems to be pretty sparse.

I expect the following code snippet to print:

`All
Even
Odd
Done`

But it prints the following instead:

`Even
Odd
Done`

```
package com.amazon.tools.desktop;

import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Target;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Task;
import org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor;

public class AntTest
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final Project project = new Project();

        final Target printAll = new Target();
        printAll.setProject(project);
        printAll.setName("printAll");
        project.addTarget(printAll);
        printAll.addTask(new LambdaTask(project, () -> System.out.println("All")));

        final Target printEven = new Target();
        printEven.setProject(project);
        printEven.setName("printEven");
        project.addTarget(printEven);
        printEven.addTask(new LambdaTask(project, () -> System.out.println("Even")));
        printEven.dependsOn("printAll");

        final Target printOdd = new Target();
        printOdd.setProject(project);
        printOdd.setName("printOdd");
        project.addTarget(printOdd);
        printOdd.addTask(new LambdaTask(project, () -> System.out.println("Odd")));
        printOdd.addDependency("printEven");


        final Target finalTarget = new Target();
        finalTarget.setProject(project);
        finalTarget.setName("finalTarget");
        project.addTarget(finalTarget);
        finalTarget.addTask(new LambdaTask(project, () -> System.out.println("Done")));
        finalTarget.addDependency("printEven");
        finalTarget.addDependency("printOdd");

        project.setExecutor(new DefaultExecutor());
        project.executeTarget("finalTarget");
    }

    public static class LambdaTask extends Task
    {
        Runnable task;

        public LambdaTask(final Project project,
                          final Runnable task)
        {
            this.task = task;
            setProject(project);
        }

        @Override
        public void execute()
        {
            task.run();
        }
    }
}
```

I can remove the `finalTarget.addDependency("printEven");` line and the target will still be executed transitively through the dependency that the printOdd target has on it, but for some reason printAll never gets executed despite the transitive dependency. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your code contains `printEven.dependsOn("printAll");`.  Did you mean to write `printEven.addDependency` instead?

Comment: That did it. So weird that two almost identical methods would behave differently.

Comment: Identical?  I haven’t seen the javadoc yet, but I assume one is an mutating action while the other is a test of a condition.  At least, that is what the verb in each method name implies.  (Just looked;  you’re right, the documentation could be better.)